# UIImagePickerController Camera preview is coming black in ios9

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am writing the below code in Xcode 7 and running app in is:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = `enter code here`(id)self;
picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But Camera preview is coming black in ios9 and  I am getting this warning:

> My Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates

Comment: I hope u r using an iPhone to test this.

Comment: yes i am using iPhone6 upgraded to ios9 and camera is coming black

Comment: Is it working for `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`??

Comment: it is not working for UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum also

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Make sure your device **SETTINGS** looks like this:

[image: iPhone 6 device settings]

Comment: the app will access your photo this alert is also not coming :(

Comment: @TaniaSahu: that alert comes only once per app... even if u have deleted it and reinstalled.

Comment: but your code is also not working it bring black camera only

Comment: my app is not coming in settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved my problem by creating a new project. May be during the upgradation some error occurred because this is happening particularly for my this project. The new project is running with camera & gallery successfully.